# WYSIWYG editor with image uploader

Tags: php, image, upload, wysiwyg

I need to find rich text editor like CKEditor last version compatible with PHP with image upload ability.

I don't want to get an editor and install plugin, i need editor with ready image uploader

can any one tell me ?

i tried Tiny editor and got image uploader but seems compatibility problem

My Question is

Rich Text Editor with image uploader ... can i got it?

thanks

Comment: have a look at Redactor http://imperavi.com/redactor/

Comment: Why not CKEditor if "like CKEditor"?

Answer (score 2):

Use TinyMCE, it should fit your needs quite well.

Extra char

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you give me direct download link for the package in demo link over here ? http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php i tried but i found many packages and don't know which one used in the demo.

Answer (score 1):

Try NicEdit. Very nice and lightweight WYSIWYG editor
http://nicedit.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try Webplus x6! It is a WYSIWYG editor I have used since x4, and it is loaded with features. It is a complete web design program, and it also allows you to easily add your own code to a page. However, it is not free, but you can check it out here: http://www.serif.com/webplus/